# ¿Que diferencia hay entre usar return o no en una funcion recursiva en c++?

Tags: c++, recursión

No entiendo cual es la diferencia entre si tiene return o no en una funcion recursiva en c++, la siguiente es una funcion recursiva para determinar si una palabra es palindroma, el tema esta en que si le quito el return ya no sirve y no entiendo el porque.

con return:

```
bool palindromo(string palabra, int n = 0){
       int p = palabra.length();

       
       if(palabra[n] == palabra[p-n-1]){
          if(n == (p/2)) return 1;
          return palindromo(palabra,++n);
       }

       return 0;      
}
```

sin return:

```
bool palindromo(string palabra, int n = 0){
       int p = palabra.length();

       if(palabra[n] == palabra[p-n-1]){
          if(n == (p/2)) return 1;
          palindromo(palabra,++n);
       }

       return 0;      
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. En parte lo respondiste tu mismo. La diferencia es que no funciona como debería. Tal vez quieras cambiar el título a la verdadera pregunta: *¿Por qué sin `return` la función no da el resultado?*

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que `palindromo()` devuelve 1 si el argumento es palíndromo y 0 si no es palíndromo.

La función es recursiva. Es decir, le entrega la tarea a una nueva instancia de `palíndromo()` y devuelve el resultado de la nueva instancia.

Si la función no tiene `return palindromo(palabra,++n);`, se ignora el resultado de la nueva instancia de `palíndromo()`. Es decir, se le entrega la tarea a una nueva instancia y se ignora su resultado si no tiene un `return`

Answer (score 0):

Si sigues el flujo del código entenderás lo que sucede.

#### Primer llamada

```
// Parámetros 
string palabra = "aba";
int n = 0;

// Código 
int p = palabra.length(); // p = 3

// true
if (palabra[n] == palabra[p-n-1]){
   // false, la ejecución continúa 
   if (n == (p/2)) return 1;
   // Entrega el control a una nueva llamada para comprobar el siguiente caracter
   palindromo(palabra, n + 1);
```

#### Segunda llamada

```
// Parámetros 
string palabra = "aba";
int n = 1;

// Código 
int p = palabra.length(); // p = 3

// true
if (palabra[n] == palabra[p-n-1]){
   // true, termina la ejecución de llamada y devuelve 1
   if (n == (p/2)) return 1;
```

#### La primera llamada retoma el control

```
    palindromo(palabra, n + 1); // 1
    // Como no hace nada con el resultado, se pierde y la ejecución continúa
}

// Finalmente devuelve 0
return 0;
```

---

Si tuviera `return`, el flujo sería igual hasta que la llamada anterior retoma el control:

```
    // La ejecución termina y devuelve el resultado
    return palindromo(palabra, n + 1);
```

Prueba depurar el código. Verás que sucede algo similar a lo que acabo de explicar.